# Macports: what exactly does the -f flag mean?

Tags: macports

Let's contrast

```
sudo port install [port_name]
```

and

```
sudo port -f install [port_name]
```

What exactly does the flag `-f` do in this case? Why don't we use the `-f` flag each time we install a new port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flag `-f` is to force the install/install. If there are dependencies that is preventing macports from installing/uninstalling, you can use the -f flag to force the install/uninstall but that is not a desirable way of installing/uninstalling.

Take a look at explanation from https://guide.macports.org/

```
sudo port uninstall libcomerr
--->  Unable to uninstall libcomerr @1.42.9_0, the following ports depend on it:
--->    kerberos5 @1.11.3_0
--->    subversion @1.8.9_0
--->    subversion-perlbindings-5.16 @1.8.9_0
Error: port uninstall failed: Please uninstall the ports that depend on libcomerr first.
```

You can recursively uninstall all ports that depend on the given port before uninstalling the port itself to work around this. To do that, use the `--follow-dependents` flag.

```
$ sudo port uninstall --follow-dependents libcomerr
```

> You can also override this safety check using the -f (force) flag.
>   Since this will obviously break the dependents you shouldn't do this
>   unless you know what you are doing.

```
$ sudo port -f uninstall libcomerr
```

Although this is an example of uninstall, you can see how -f flag works.

Answer (score 1):

On installation, the force flag is used to force activation in case a file that would be provided by the port you are installing already exists on your system. Without the force flag, MacPorts will abort the installation and warn you; with the flag, MacPorts will rename the existing file (appending .mp_$timestamp).

Forcing may become necessary if you have previously uninstalled a version of MacPorts but not cleaned up all the files it provided, or if a third-party installer built using MacPorts installed files into `/opt/local` (which is wrong, but still happens sometimes).

Because overwriting is not safe behavior, it isn't the default. This is also the reason why you should not always specify `-f`.